# MDXQuery - Currentmember with his parent

Tags: mdx, parent, cube

I'm trying to write a MDX query that would display all my products and the subgroups (hierarchy parent) that they belong to. While the task seems rather trivial i still can't figure it out. Here is my MDX query.

```
select 
    {
    [Products].[Hierarchy].currentmember.parent
    }
on 0,
    {
    [Products].[Hierarchy].[Product].members
    }
on 1
from [CUBE]
```

I also tried

```
    select 
    {
Ancestor([Products].[Hierarchy].currentmember, 
         [Products].[Hierarchy].[Subgroup]) 
    }
on 0,
    {
    [Products].[Hierarchy].[Product].members
    }
on 1
from [CUBE];
```

But all I get from it is a gray list of products without any actual column. Any help/tips would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: these look like they would error? an error along the lines of "already using this hierarchy on the 0 axis"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use the same hierarchy then you can only use it on one axis - there are 3 axis in context - `ON COLUMNS` / `ON ROWS` / `WHERE`.

So putting `[Products].[Hierarchy].` `ON COLUMNS` and also `ON ROWS` would throw an exception.

What you can do is move some of the logic into a `WITH` clause and move the narrative into the `Measures` dimension:

```
WITH 
MEMBER [Measures].[ProdName] AS
  Ancestor(
    [Products].[Hierarchy].currentmember, 
    [Products].[Hierarchy].[Subgroup]
  ).MEMBER_CAPTION
SELECT 
  [Measures].[ProdName] ON 0,
  [Products].[Hierarchy].[Product].MEMBERS ON 1
FROM [CUBE];
```

You could make use of your attribute hierarchies and do something like this:

```
SELECT 
  {} ON 0,
  [Products].[Product].[Product]
 *[Products].[Subgroup].[Subgroup]
    ON 1
FROM [CUBE];
```

Comment: Thanks, thats exacly what I needed! As for the second option, I actually tried something identical with select null on columns and select crossjoin and it worked, but somehow I thought it was a cheap wayout. As for the first code, it works exacly how I wanted it to work, and i was thinking about something on similar lines. So the key was using the MEMBER_CAPTION property. Gonna read some more on that.

Comment: This should list all the properties that can be used: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms145528.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: @some if you like mdx then I'd suggest this tool `MDXStudio` as it is better than SSMS: https://www.sqlbi.com/tools/mdx-studio/